# Pausensetzung in Gedicht

Tags: poetry, typography

Die zweite Strophe des Gedichts »der brennende hain«* von Jan Wagner  lautet:

> an seinem dorn: das friedliche gemälde,
>   das einmal da
>   war, schien verschwunden
>   zu sein, als wir vorm fensterrahmen standen,

Natürlich gelten die Gesetze der Interpunktion und Orthographie für Lyrik – insbesondere moderne Lyrik – nicht wie für Prosa, und die Typographie als gestalterisches Element kann eine andere Rolle einnehmen.

Trotzdem:
Wo sollen in dieser Strophe die Pausen gesetzt werden (Prosodie): am Ende der Zeile oder nach den Kommas?

Die Pausen am Ende der Zeilen zu setzen erscheint mir natürlicher, entstellt aber die Sinneinheiten und ist nicht gut zu lesen.

Die Pause nach dem Komma (nach *war* und *sein*) zu setzen, erhält die Sinneinheiten.
Wenn das die intendierte Lesung ist, hätte die Strophe auch so gesetzt werden können:

> an seinem dorn: das friedliche gemälde,
>   das einmal da war,
>   schien verschwunden zu sein,
>   als wir vorm fensterrahmen standen,

Auch typographisch entsteht hier kein Nachteil gegenüber der tatsächlichen Anordnung.

Ich bin sicher, dass diese Entscheidung bewusst getroffen wurde:
Was könnte der Grund dafür sein?
Oder sollte man die Pausen doch am Ende der Zeile setzen, eventuell mit weiteren Pausen nach den Kommas?

---

* <sub>Jan Wagner: *Selbstporträt mit Bienenschwarm*. *Ausgewählte Gedichte*. Fischer: Frankfurt am Main 2018, 112.</sub>

Comment: Ask the author for the intend.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Wie ich schrieb, die Regeln sind nicht fest. Natürlich kann man sagen: »Frag den Autor, alles andere ist Spekulation.« Wenn man aber davon ausgeht, dass es einen Sinn gibt, dann könnte der auch erkennbar sein(?). Vermutlich sind manche Nutzer in Lyrik bewandert genug, hier etwas zu sehen, das ich nicht sehen kann. Und vielleicht gibt es Konventionen, die ich nicht kenne.

Comment: Lyrik involviert Kreativität, und mithin Brüche zu vorgegebenen Regeln (s. Ernst Jandl). Deine Frage ist m.E. nicht finit beantwortbar hinsichtlich der Korrektheit. Daher mein Close Vote.

Comment: Die Kommasetzung ist im Deutschen weitgehend durch die grammatikalische Struktur des Satzes vorgegeben. Daher muss ein Komma nicht zwangsläufig mit einer Sprechpause verbunden sein.

Comment: Frag den Author ob er noch weiß, was er sich dabei gedacht hat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nun, es sind ja sog. harte Enjambements, die hier wie zuvor bei anderen Autoren (Celan z.B.) in recht hohem Maße verstörend wirken. Der Kunstgriff sorgt hier dafür, dass Form und Inhalt einander in besonders hohem Maße, aber nicht in der konventionellen, zu erwartenden Weise entsprechen: "das friedliche gemälde" scheint nicht nur verschwunden, sondern geradezu 'kaputt' zu sein; die enttäuschte Erwartungshaltung der "wir" findet ihren Niederschlag in einer 'zerstückelten' Sprache.

Um deine Frage nach den Sprechpausen zu beantworten: Ich ganz persönlich würde die Pausen jeweils am Vers-Ende setzen, da, wo Wagner die Bruchstellen gesetzt hat - in der Unterstellung, dass er genau das intendiert hat.